# How to integrate 3rd Party projects in Android Studio?

Tags: android, dependencies

I found this 3rd Part party project [CircularImageView](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView) which adds circular image to an Android App. The readme file says to use the following code on Gradle:

```
compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
```

But it seems that there is a bug in the project which does not allow the dependencies to be loaded properly.

Is there a way to import the project in my App manually? Just like we add JAR dependencies to Android app?

N.B.: I do not have a jar of the project

Comment: Have you synchronized your project with Gradle files?

Comment: Yes I synchronized it